# AJAX overlay if user session expires Wordpress frontend

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

If a **user session expires**  in `wp-admin` a user is logged out and with the page still open, WordPress overlays a modal login.

How can I register a user **session expiring/logged out from another location** and initiate an overlay from the frontend?

Currently, we are bringing up the login form via Javascript with button `on('click',...)` and the action of logging in and out is handled within **functions.php**

```
$('a#show_login').on('click', function(e){
    $('body').prepend('<div class="login_overlay"></div>');
    $('form#login').fadeIn(500);
    $('div.login_overlay, form#login a.close').on('click', function(){
        $('div.login_overlay').remove();
        $('form#login').hide();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Is there a way to identify the user session expiring in real time, then initiating the overlay?** I have looked for other references and documentation but cannot find a solution in achieving what is happening in the backend of Wordpress. Ideally, being able to use this on the frontend with the same hooks/actions (if they exist?) would be the perfect solution.

If not, perhaps a combination of AJAX and an action to replicate what the backend is doing for timed out sessions.

**Here is the function to initiate the current overlay form**

```
function ajax_login_init(){

wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
));

// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}
```

**and an example of the backend expired session**

[image: example backend]

**Please note:** I do not want to use a plugin to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223721/interim-login-form-on-frontend

```
function login_session_expired() {
// we only care to add scripts and styles if the user is logged in.
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    // add javascript file
    wp_register_script( 'wp_auth_check', '/wp-includes/js/wp-auth-check.js' , array('heartbeat'), false, 1);
    wp_localize_script( 'wp_auth_check', 'authcheckL10n', array(
        'beforeunload' => __('Your session has expired. You can log in again from this page or go to the login page.'),
        'interval' => apply_filters( 'wp_auth_check_interval', 1 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS ), // default interval is 3 minutes
    ) );
    wp_enqueue_script ('wp_auth_check');

    // add css file
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp_auth_check','/wp-includes/css/wp-auth-check.css', array( 'dashicons' ), NULL, 'all' );

    // add the login html to the page
    add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_auth_check_html', 5 );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'login_session_expired' );

// make sure the stylesheet appears on the lightboxed login iframe
function login_session_expired_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp_auth_check','/wp-includes/css/wp-auth-check.css', array( 'dashicons' ), NULL, 'all' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'login_session_expired_styles' );
```